# Recursive CTE T- SQL lowest value in the chain

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

Here is the table set up.

```
create table ids 
(
     id int not null, 
     new_id int not null
)
GO

insert ids (id, new_id) values(290, 190)
insert ids (id, new_id) values(390, 190)
insert ids (id, new_id) values(490, 190)
insert ids (id, new_id) values(580, 280)
insert ids (id, new_id) values(680, 280)
insert ids (id, new_id) values(280, 150)
insert ids (id, new_id) values(780, 150)
insert ids (id, new_id) values(990, 620)
insert ids (id, new_id) values(150, 140)
GO
```

The data

```
id  new_id
-----------
290 190
390 190
490 190
580 280
680 280
280 150
780 150
990 620
150 140
```

Id get resolved to new id, the new ids will always be lower than the initial id.

I want the ids and their lowest new_ids.

My attempt so far is like this.

```
with cte_ids as
(
    select
        a.id,
        a.new_id
    from
        ids a
    left join
        ids b on a.new_id = b.id
    where 
        b.id is null

    union all

    select
        c.id,
        c.new_id
    from
        ids  c
    join 
        cte_ids d on d.id = c.new_id
)
select * from cte_ids
```

Which returns a result of

```
id  new_id
------------
290 190
390 190
490 190
990 620
150 140
280 150
780 150
580 280
680 280
```

Result is incorrect because id 580 should be 140 because 580 became 280 then 280 became 150 and then 150 became 140.

The expected result is

```
id  new_id
------------
290 190
390 190
490 190
580 140
680 140
280 140
780 140
990 620
150 140
```

How to get this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `CASE` to calculate `lowest_new_id`:

```
with cte_ids as
(
    select a.id, a.new_id, lowest_new_id = a.new_id
    from ids a
    left join ids b on a.new_id = b.id
    where b.id is null
    union all
    select c.id, c.new_id, 
           lowest_new_id = CASE WHEN d.lowest_new_id < c.new_id 
                                THEN d.lowest_new_id ELSE c.new_id 
                           END
    from ids  c
    join cte_ids d on d.id = c.new_id
)
select * 
from cte_ids;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7fe0b1206445e8dc97ec503586909866)**

Answer (score 2):

As I understand your question, you want to follow the relationship for each `id` in the original table, and bring the latest available `new_id`.

Consider:

```
with cte_ids as (
    select id, new_id, 1 lvl from ids
    union all
    select c.id, i.new_id, c.lvl + 1
    from cte_ids c 
    inner join ids i on i.id = c.new_id
)
select id, new_id
from cte_ids c
where c.lvl = (select max(c1.lvl) from cte_ids c1 where c1.id = c.id)
order by id
```

Rationale:

- the anchor of the recursive query select all `id`s
- then the recursive part follows the relationships, while keeping track of the original `id`, and increments a counter called `lvl` at each iteration
- the outer query filters on the highest `lvl` per `id`

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1646f02e4c9c3fc79af375456f027f96)**:

```
 id | new_id
--: | -----:
150 |    140
280 |    140
290 |    190
390 |    190
490 |    190
580 |    140
680 |    140
780 |    140
990 |    620
```